# Join two tables and filter them with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem getting the SQL output I want.

I have two tables like this:

**tblOrder**

```
ID    User    Status
1      1         0
2      1         0
3      2         1
```

**tblOrderItem**

```
ID   OrderID     Product    Quantity
1       1           A           2
2       1           B           1
3       2           A           3
4       2           B           1
5       2           C           1
6       3           A           2
```

I want to get an output table where I can see all orders with status 0 and also see all items in the order, like this:

**Output**

```
 OrderID      User    Product     Quantity
    1           1        A            2
    1           1        B            1
    2           1        A            3
    2           1        B            1
    2           1        C            1
```

All SQL I have tried with different versions of INNER JOIN etc only gets the first row with every OrderID (`tblOrder.ID`). How should I write my SQL query to get the result I want?

Next I want to print the output with PHP in JSON format for a C# program running on another device to get the result. In the end the result should be inserted in a class like:

```
Public class orderobject

{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public String Product[] { get; set; } // Dont know if correct way to make array this way
    public int Quantity[] { get; set; }
}
```

The result will finaly be inserted in a list with objects of this class. So every entry in the list is a seperate order with all wanted order data.

Am I thinking wrong or is the way I want my SQL the best to get only one web request? I can reorganize the result in the C# code ant insert it to the class there.

Comment: Use the `join` on  `OrderID` and `ID` and then add the filter for `status=0` using `where` clause, to get the result you want. As far as `C#` class you should use the `List<string>`  instead of the `string[]` as list gives various inbuilt functionality to manipulate.

Comment: How should I use join? All ways I have set the SQL up it only returns one row per tblOrder.ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Coder of Code [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256560/sql-get-all-rows-from-first-table-with-specific-valu-and-add-all-related-rows-fr#comment46716410_29256560) you should `JOIN` Both the table, apply `O.Status = 0` using the `WHERE` clause and then use `ORDER BY` to order the results in the required way using `ASC` or `DESC` based on the ascending or descending order like below. Its better to go with [`List<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) as it has methods to search, sort, and manipulate lists.

```
SELECT OI.OrderID, O.User, OI.Product, OI.Quantity
FROM tblOrder O
INNER JOIN tblOrderItem OI ON O.ID = OI.OrderID
WHERE O.Status = 0
ORDER BY OI.OrderID ASC, OI.Product ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I found that I had done was write `O.ID = OI.ID` instead of `O.ID = OI.OrderID`. Thats why I only got one row per ID. 
I should have seen that but I only thought of other problems. Thanks for the help!